# How to use Zsh with msysGit

Tags: git, zsh

msysGit comes with an Explorer shell extension showing `Git Bash Here` in the context menu of a folder which opens a Bash prompt in the selected folder.

How can I use Zsh instead of Bash as the shell for this command window?

Comment: I'm reasonably sure you can't. `msysgit` gives a "Unix-like shell". I don't *think* it's a full implementation of `bash`. What problem are you trying to solve with `zsh` on Windows? If you're after a full shell, you can use `bash/zsh` in Cygwin, giving an (almost) full POSIX environment in Windows. Re-reading your question: are you after a way to open a `zsh`-based command window in the current directory from Windows Explorer using a mouse shortcut?

Comment: I guess yes, cygwin provides a good POSIX environment, except that I am under the impression, that msysGit performs much better than cygwin's git and one cannot use msysGit from cygwin due the the way consoles are treated.

Answer (score 5):

The built-in Bash that msysGit provides is built on top of `conhost.exe`. That makes it terrible compared to, e.g., xterm (clipboard, text input/output, history, etc.).

The workaround I'm currently using when on Windows is I use the latest msysGit + Cygwin mintty with Bash. That gives me a decent shell with a recent and fast Git. With that approach you can use other shells, like Zsh. Beware that the tradeoffs include Git not being able to use your PAGER (I had to alias things like `git log` to `git log|less`).

Answer (score 2):

MsysGit does not support other shells than the built-in Bash.

You may consider using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) - if you can't live without Zsh (i understand you) - which also provides a [git-package](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fgit%2Fgit-1.7.9-1&grep=git).

Unfortunately this package is pretty old (v1.7.9 is from Jan '12) which may cause problems in the interaction with newer repositories.

Answer (score 2):

[Babun](http://babun.github.io/) is a variant that is easy to set up. It is based on Cygwin, provides Zsh (including [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)) and Git ready to use out of the box.

Technically, it is not using Zsh with *msysGit* since Babun includes its own version of Git. Furthermore, Babun takes about twice the space needed by msysGit (including Git Bash). However, it may become a viable alternative thanks to the easy setup and further usage possibilities in comparison to msysGit.

**Update:** Babun project is discontinued. On Windows 10, you can use [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) instead and install all requested software (like Git and Zsh) using the package manager of the chosen Linux distro.

Comment: Babun being 32 bit only is a crippling limitation for running other programs under it usefully. Also, the maintainers are AWOL since 2016. I do not recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

you should install pacman first.
you can install msys then copy following files to git for windows install dir.

```sh
./etc/pacman.conf
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/.gpg-v21-migrated
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/crls.d/DIR.txt
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/gpg.conf
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/openpgp-revocs.d/95B7E06B8C47127F398481080BDA45A606729940.rev
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/1124CC687F416E4D7C43EB618BECDD023E787046.key
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/pubring.gpg~
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/secring.gpg
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/tofu.db
./etc/pacman.d/gnupg/trustdb.gpg
./etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw32
./etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.mingw64
./etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.msys
./usr/bin/pacboy
./usr/bin/paccache
./usr/bin/pacdiff
./usr/bin/paclist
./usr/bin/paclog-pkglist
./usr/bin/pacman-conf.exe
./usr/bin/pacman-db-upgrade
./usr/bin/pacman-key
./usr/bin/pacman-rec-filename-grep
./usr/bin/pacman.exe
./usr/bin/pacscripts
./usr/bin/pacsearch
./usr/bin/pacsort.exe
./usr/bin/pactoys
```

I just copy all binary start with `pac` from /usr/bin/ dir.
now you have a pacman. install zsh use `pacman -S zsh` command.

see tutorial from https://medium.com/@borekb/zsh-via-msys2-on-windows-3964a943b1ce